# Reporting bash script failures to Sentry

Tags: bash, sentry

If I run a bash script with `set -e` it aborts with an error. I am running some maintenance shell script, along with Python application code, and I'd like to report errors from the shell scripts to Sentry as well.

What options do I have? What kind of traps bash provides and what kind of command line integration there exists for pushing errors to Sentry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For bash scripts you can enable automatic error sending by using the sentry-cli bash hook. That enables set -e and will send a sentry event for unhandled errors.
https://docs.sentry.io/product/cli/send-event/

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for something similar myself, and came across https://github.com/Doist/raven-sh . Not had chance to use it yet, so can't vouch for how well it works.